# How to switch image represantion in numpy without rotating the image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have an image that has the dimension: (3,1080,1920).

I need to convert it to (1080,1920,3). To do so I simply transpose the matrix, but this results in: (1920,1080,3). To have the needed size I would need rotate it after this by 90°.

Now I want to know if there is an easier way, that will reduce the work ?

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

#...snippet:
bgr = np.asarray([blue,green,red],dtype=np.uint8)

bgr = bgr.T;
#now do 90° degree turn, but maybe there is a simpler way?
```

Comment: Note that rotating will not be the same than transposing. In both cases you will end in the correct orientation, but with an horizontally mirrored image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.transpose()` and you can specify the axes as a second parameter.

In your case you want `axes = (1, 2, 0)`

Example:

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.random.rand(3,1080,1920)
my_matrix.shape

    (3,1080,1920)

my_matrix = np.transpose(my_matrix, axes=(1, 2, 0))
my_matrix.shape

    (1080,1920,3)
```